# What is the problem in my gaussian input?

Tags: computational-chemistry, gaussian, software-assistance

I want to obtain the single point energy of a Ni-complex molecule, with a mixed basis set using the Gen keyword. The input is:

```
%nprocshared=4
%mem=1500MB
%chk=61++.chk
# b3lyp/gen

title

atom coordinates

P C H N O 0
6-311++G(d,p)
****
Ni 0
cc-pVDZ
```

but I get this error:

QPErr --- A syntax error was detected in the input line.

'

Last state= "Top"
TCursr=      2959 LCursr=         0
Error reading general basis specification.
Error termination via Lnk1e in C:\G09W\l301.exe
Job cpu time:       0 days  0 hours  0 minutes  0.0 seconds.

I would be grateful if you could help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add the name of basis set again for Ni at the end of the input

Your input should be

```
%nprocshared=4
%mem=1500MB
%chk=61++.chk
# b3lyp/gen

title

atom coordinates

P C H N O 0
6-311++G(d,p)
****
Ni 0
cc-pVDZ
****

Ni 0
cc-pVDZ
```

Comment: Could just be that I haven't run Gaussian in awhile, but doesn't it just need the last `****` to finish the basis specification (and one last blank line to end the file)? I don't see why the specification for `Ni` would need to be repeated.

Comment: You are right. There are two option: 1- He needs two blank lines not only one blank line, or he can do what I did to solve the problem and include ECP.

Comment: Note that the use of these basis sets is ill-advised for DFT: cc-pVXZ is suboptimal and Pople sets are obsolete, the 6-311G sets are especially infamous for their many errors. You can just replace b3lyp/gen with b3lyp/def2SVP for a modern split-valence polarized basis, or b3lyp/def2TZVP for polarized triple-zeta basis.